# best practice for returning a variable length string in c

Tags: c, string, function

I have a string function that accepts a pointer to a source string and returns a pointer to a destination string. This function currently works, but I'm worried I'm not following the best practice regrading malloc, realloc, and free.

The thing that's different about my function is that the length of the destination string is not the same as the source string, so realloc() has to be called inside my function. I know from looking at the docs...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/

that the memory address might change after the realloc. This means I have can't "pass by reference" like a C programmer might for other functions, I have to return the new pointer.

So the prototype for my function is:

```
//decode a uri encoded string
char *net_uri_to_text(char *);
```

I don't like the way I'm doing it because I have to free the pointer after running the function:

```
char * chr_output = net_uri_to_text("testing123%5a%5b%5cabc");
printf("%s\n", chr_output); //testing123Z[\abc
free(chr_output);
```

Which means that malloc() and realloc() are called inside my function and free() is called outside my function.

I have a background in high level languages, (perl, plpgsql, bash) so my instinct is proper encapsulation of such things, but that might not be the best practice in C.

The question: Is my way best practice, or is there a better way I should follow?

## full example

Compiles and runs with two warnings on unused argc and argv arguments, you can safely ignore those two warnings.

## example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *net_uri_to_text(char *);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char * chr_input = "testing123%5a%5b%5cabc";
  char * chr_output = net_uri_to_text(chr_input);
  printf("%s\n", chr_output);
  free(chr_output);
  return 0;
}

//decodes uri-encoded string
//send pointer to source string
//return pointer to destination string
//WARNING!! YOU MUST USE free(chr_result) AFTER YOU'RE DONE WITH IT OR YOU WILL GET A MEMORY LEAK!
char *net_uri_to_text(char * chr_input) {
  //define variables
  int int_length = strlen(chr_input);
  int int_new_length = int_length;
  char * chr_output = malloc(int_length);
  char * chr_output_working = chr_output;
  char * chr_input_working = chr_input;
  int int_output_working = 0;
  unsigned int uint_hex_working;
  //while not a null byte
  while(*chr_input_working != '\0') {
    //if %
    if (*chr_input_working == *"%") {
      //then put correct char in
      sscanf(chr_input_working + 1, "%02x", &uint_hex_working);
      *chr_output_working = (char)uint_hex_working;
      //printf("special char:%c, %c, %d<\n", *chr_output_working, (char)uint_hex_working, uint_hex_working);
      //realloc
      chr_input_working++;
      chr_input_working++;
      int_new_length -= 2;
      chr_output = realloc(chr_output, int_new_length);
      //output working must be the new pointer plys how many chars we've done
      chr_output_working = chr_output + int_output_working;
    } else {
      //put char in
      *chr_output_working = *chr_input_working;
    }
    //increment pointers and number of chars in output working
    chr_input_working++;
    chr_output_working++;
    int_output_working++;
  }
  //last null byte
  *chr_output_working = '\0';
  return chr_output;
}
```

Comment: I like the `*"%"` part. :D

Comment: Thanks, i just found out that `'%'` works. :)

Comment: If you wrap your code between backticks (`), then they will be formatted as code

Comment: This `int int_length = strlen(chr_input); ... char * chr_output = malloc(int_length);` looks dangerous. If the string does not shrink during conversion the allocated memory is one byte too short. The strings's `0`-terminator cannot be stored savely then.

Comment: So `char * chr_output = malloc(int_length + 1);` would be correct then,
and this line would be changed: `chr_output = realloc(chr_output, int_new_length);` to `chr_output = realloc(chr_output, int_new_length + 1);` right?

Comment: And yes, the concept of having a function return freshly allocated memory looks ok to me (see `strdup()`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly ok to return `malloc`'d buffers from functions in C, as long as you document the fact that they do. Lots of libraries do that, even though no function in the standard library does.

If you can compute (a not too pessimistic upper bound on) the number of characters that need to be written to the buffer cheaply, you can offer a function that does that and let the user call it.

It's also possible, but much less convenient, to accept a buffer to be filled in; I've seen quite a few libraries that do that like so:

```
/*
 * Decodes uri-encoded string encoded into buf of length len (including NUL).
 * Returns the number of characters written. If that number is less than len,
 * nothing is written and you should try again with a larger buffer.
 */
size_t net_uri_to_text(char const *encoded, char *buf, size_t len)
{
    size_t space_needed = 0;

    while (decoding_needs_to_be_done()) {
        // decode characters, but only write them to buf
        // if it wouldn't overflow;
        // increment space_needed regardless
    }
    return space_needed;
}
```

Now the caller is responsible for the allocation, and would do something like

```
size_t len = SOME_VALUE_THAT_IS_USUALLY_LONG_ENOUGH;
char *result = xmalloc(len);

len = net_uri_to_text(input, result, len);
if (len > SOME_VALUE_THAT_IS_USUALLY_LONG_ENOUGH) {
    // try again
    result = xrealloc(input, result, len);
}
```

(Here, `xmalloc` and `xrealloc` are "safe" allocating functions that I made up to skip NULL checks.)

Comment: Two nice aspects about expecting the caller to pass a buffer (+ size of it): 1. The caller may know the maximum length up front, so he can decide to use an array allocated on the stack. 2.) The ownership of the memory does not get transferred, i.e. both allocation and deallocation happen on the caller site - this is critical on Windows in case the caller is in a different DLL than the callee (it's forbidden to allocate memory in one DLL and release it in another on Windows, since the memory-manager is per-module, not per-process).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I didn't know about that. I do know that it allows custom memory managers to be used instead of `malloc`, which is useful on Unix as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK to return newly-`malloc`-ed (and possibly internally `realloc`ed) values from functions, you just need to document that you are doing so (as you do here).

Other obvious items:

- Instead of `int int_length` you might want to use `size_t`.  This is "an unsigned type" (usually `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`) that is the appropriate type for lengths of strings and arguments to `malloc`.
- You need to allocate n+1 bytes initially, where n is the length of the string, as `strlen` does not include the terminating 0 byte.
- You should check for `malloc` failing (returning `NULL`).  If your function will pass the failure on, document that in the function-description comment.
- `sscanf` is pretty heavy-weight for converting the two hex bytes.  Not *wrong*, except that you're not checking whether the conversion succeeds (what if the input is malformed? you can of course decide that this is the caller's problem but in general you might want to handle that).  You can use `isxdigit` from `<ctype.h>` to check for hexadecimal digits, and/or `strtoul` to do the conversion.
- Rather than doing one `realloc` for every `%` conversion, you might want to do a final "shrink realloc" if desirable.  Note that if you allocate (say) 50 bytes for a string and find it requires only 49 including the final 0 byte, it may not be worth doing a `realloc` after all.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that C is low-level enough to force the programmer to get her memory management right. In particular, there's nothing wrong with returning a `malloc()`ated string. It's a common idiom to return mallocated obejcts and have the caller `free()` them.

And anyways, if you don't like this approach, you can always take a pointer to the string and modify it from inside the function (after the last use, it will still need to be `free()`d, though).

One thing, however, that I don't think is necessary is explicitly shrinking the string. If the new string is shorter than the old one, there's obviously enough room for it in the memory chunk of the old string, so you don't need to `realloc()`.

(Apart from the fact that you forgot to allocate one extra byte for the terminating NUL character, of course...)

And, as always, you can just return a different pointer each time the function is called, and you don't even need to call `realloc()` at all.

If you accept one last piece of good advice: it's advisable to `const`-qualify your input strings, so the caller can ensure that you don't modify them. Using this approach, you can safely call the function on string literals, for example.

All in all, I'd rewrite your function like this:

```
char *unescape(const char *s)
{
    size_t l = strlen(s);
    char *p = malloc(l + 1), *r = p;

    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%') {
            char buf[3] = { s[1], s[2], 0 };
            *p++ = strtol(buf, NULL, 16); // yes, I prefer this over scanf()
            s += 3;
        } else {
            *p++ = *s++;
        }
    }

    *p = 0;
    return r;
}
```

And call it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    const char *in = "testing123%5a%5b%5cabc";
    char *out = unescape(in);
    printf("%s\n", out);
    free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welp, I didn't mention `size_t` and `strtol()` explicitly, and I've also assumed that `malloc()` never fails... Watch out!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem in a slightly different way. Personally, I would split your function in two. The first function to calculate the size you need to malloc. The second would write the output string to the given pointer (which has been allocated outside of the function). That saves several calls to realloc, and will keep the complexity the same. A possible function to find the size of the new string is:

```
int getNewSize (char *string) {
    char *i = string;
    int size = 0, percent = 0;
    for (i, size; *i != '\0'; i++, size++) {
        if (*i == '%')
            percent++;
    }
    return size - percent * 2;
}
```

However, as mentioned in other answers there is no problem in returning a malloc'ed buffer as long as you document it!

Comment: Note that if you do decide to refactor like this, you can have your "function to calculate space" *also* verify that the URL is well formed (does not have things like %-! in the middle).  Sometimes people go for a sort of hybrid approach, too: verify, optionally malloc, optionally convert into buffer (whether user provided or malloc-ed), return bunch of information (via `struct` or caller-supplied pointers), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally what was already mentioned in the other postings, you should also document the fact that the string is reallocated. If your code is called with a static string or a string allocated with `alloca`, you may not reallocate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right to be concerned about splitting up mallocs and frees. As a rule, whatever makes it, owns it and should free it.

In this case, where the strings are relatively small, one good procedure is to make the string buffer larger than any possible string it could contain. For example, URLs have a de facto limit of about 2000 characters, so if you malloc 10000 characters you can store any possible URL.

Another trick is to store both the length and capacity of the string at its front, so that `(int)*mystring == length of string` and `(int)*(mystring + 4) == capacity` of string. Thus, the string itself only starts at the 8th position `*(mystring+8)`. By doing this you can pass around a single pointer to a string and always know how long it is and how much memory capacity the string has. You can make macros that automatically generate these offsets and make "pretty code".

The value of using buffers this way is you do not need to do a reallocation. The new value overwrites the old value and you update the length at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I think the 'encode size of string in the first few bytes' technique is very nasty, since it's rather uncommon (I never saw it in practice) and the compiler can't help if you forget about this fact. So if you have a string "Hello", printing it might just get a single character printed since most of the bytes of the initial int are zero. Not a nice thing to debug. :-/

Comment: When you use the content of the string you refer to it as '*(mystring+8)'. For example: printf( "%s\n", *(mystring+8) ); a macro can be used if wanted. The alternative is to define a structure instead, but then you have to deal with nested pointers. In my experience, it is easier to use the method I describe than use nested pointers when manipulating short strings.